# client-error-bad-request for Get-Job-Attributes (no URI) from localhost

Tags: fedora, printing, cups

I'm trying to set up a local printer (no networking involved). The printer is connected via USB. The printer works (on MS Windows). The problem is with CUPS as far as I can tell. I can't understand the error message, and I can neither find an explanation for the laundry list of settings in a handful of CUPS configuration files, nor can I find any description of this error and what can it mean.

If I try to print a test page, the log looks like this:

```
I [22/Dec/2014:01:12:15 +0200] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/printers.cgi" (pid=6154)
E [22/Dec/2014:01:12:15 +0200] Returning IPP client-error-bad-request for Get-Job-Attributes (no URI) from localhost
I [22/Dec/2014:01:12:20 +0200] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/printers.cgi" (pid=6183)
I [22/Dec/2014:01:12:22 +0200] Saving job.cache...
I [22/Dec/2014:01:12:22 +0200] Saving subscriptions.conf...
I [22/Dec/2014:01:12:30 +0200] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/printers.cgi" (pid=6200)
```

I bet it must be some idiotic default setting buried somewhere, but I just have no idea what would it be. Please advise!

If it is at all important, the printer is Xerox Phaser 3010, OS is Fedora 18. The drivers provided by the manufacturer are not installable (maybe with some effort and understanding one could install them by hand, but out of the box the RPM pre/post-install scripts break). So I'm using a slightly different driver (for Phaser 3110).